Enumerate is Returning A None Type
I was following an API Development course when I ran into this problem. The function is supposed to check each posts of their unique id, and then returning it's index if the id of the posts matches (by using enumerate). But somehow, it always returns a None Type.
Let's say that I have hardcoded these specific posts with their properties:
my_posts = [{"title": "title of post 1", "content": "content of post1", "id": 1}, {"title": "Favorite Foods", "content": "I like pizza", "id": 2}]

This is the function that would be used to find the index of the posts I am trying to delete:
def find_index_post(id):
    for i, p in enumerate(my_posts):
        if p["id"] == id:
            return i

And this, would be the delete function/logic:
@app.delete("/posts/{id}")
def delete_post(id):
    index = find_index_post(id)

    my_posts.pop(index)
    return{'message': f"post with id '{id}' is deleted"}

The problem is, the find_index_post(id) always returns a None to the index variable.
But when I debugged it by changing find_index_post(id) to find_index_post(1), it worked and returned the value of 0 to the index variable, which is correct.
Is there something wrong with how I processed my data type or is it some crucial detail that I had missed. Thank you.

I guess id is a string, not an int.

You sure that id is an integer and not a string in your delete_posts function?

You are not accounting for the circumstance where id cannot be found in your list of dictionaries. Also, don't use id as a variable name as it will shadow the built-in function of the same name

I think the issue is that you passed id as a string. But in your posts data, id is integer, not string. So I think you need to update your code a little bit like below.
def find_index_post(id):
    id = int(id) # Convert id to interger
    for i, p in enumerate(my_posts):
        if p["id"] == id:
            return i


There are three issues here:

The default return of the function is None
Avoid shadowing built-in names like id
Use typed path-parameters to parse as int

See how they can be fixed.
(1) Add a default return value
Like commented by SIGHUP: When the given id can not be found, the if-condition never reaches and does not return, instead the end of the function is reached and then default return is None.
So, you could add a default return at the end for the case when if is not reached and id not found.
def find_index_post(post_id):
    for i, p in enumerate(my_posts):
        if p["id"] == post_id:
            return i
    return -1

As a consequence, the chosen default value of -1 will remove the last element when passed to pop(index) later. So we need an exceptional handling here - also to report the not-found error to the client:
@app.delete("/posts/{post_id}")
def delete_post(post_id):
    index = find_index_post(post_id)
    
    if index < 0:
        return {'message': f"post with id '{post_id}' not found"}
    
    my_posts.pop(index)
    return {'message': f"post with id '{post_id}' is deleted"}

(2) Rename the parameter to a more specific
Shown as color in syntax-highlighting, maybe by code-inspection of your IDE and advised by SIGHUP's comment too: Avoid shadowing internal names, be specific and meaningful when naming variables or parameters.
@app.delete("/posts/{post_id}")
def delete_post(post_id):
    index = find_index_post(post_id)

    my_posts.pop(index)
    return {'message': f"post with id '{post_id}' is deleted"}

and
def find_index_post(post_id):
    for i, p in enumerate(my_posts):
        if p["id"] == post_id:
            return i
    return -1

(3) Use type hints and conversion from your web-framework
You could let your web-framework convert the path-parameter to the desired type like int.
See for example FastAPI: Path parameters with types. Then it would be:
@app.delete("/posts/{post_id}")
def delete_post(post_id: int):
    index = find_index_post(post_id)

    my_posts.pop(index)
    return{'message': f"post with id '{post_id}' is deleted"}

This automatic conversion has the same intent and effect as answered by Youth Dream
